# Slow MySQL Query -- CASE Within JOIN

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have two tables: *all_ufo* (U) and *rights* (R). See ERD:
[image]

*rights* is the parent table. *all_ufo* is the child.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM all_ufo U
LEFT JOIN rights R
ON CASE
  WHEN U.UPC IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT UPC
    FROM rights
    WHERE UPC IS NOT NULL
    AND Channels IS NULL)
  THEN R.UPC 
    AND U.UPC = R.UPC

  WHEN U.Artist IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Artist
    FROM rights
    WHERE Artist IS NOT NULL
    AND Channels IS NULL)
  THEN R.Artist
    AND U.Artist = R.Artist

  WHEN U.Label IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Label
    FROM rights
    WHERE Label IS NOT NULL
    AND Channels IS NULL)
  THEN R.Label
    AND U.Label = R.Label
END
;
```

The *rights* table is a little weird: it has 3 levels of contract, and I want to match each line item in *all_ufo* to one and only one contract.

The query looks for a match in R for every line in U (where there is one), starting with UPC, then Artist, then Label.

Here's a sample of the R table. There's one line here representing each kind of entry in the table (NULL values show up here as the string "NULL", but in the database they are actually null):

And here's a sample of 20 random lines from U:

On my sample data (20 lines), I get an expected result. But when I run it on the whole table (about 600K lines), it runs for an hour or so and then terminates.

I also tried separating the R table into three separate tables, one for each type contract. Here's the MySQL script I tried, and it failed due to incorrect SQL (?) :

```
SELECT *
FROM all_ufo U
CASE
WHEN U.UPC IN (
SELECT DISTINCT UPC
FROM Contracts_Release
WHERE Channels IS NULL)
THEN LEFT JOIN Contracts_Release R
ON (U.UPC = R.UPC
AND R.ContractLevel = 'ReleaseLevel')

WHEN U.Artist IN (
SELECT DISTINCT Artist
FROM Contracts_Artist
WHERE Channels IS NULL)
THEN LEFT JOIN Contracts_Artist R
ON U.Artist = R.Artist
AND R.ContractLevel = 'ArtistLevel'

WHEN U.Label IN (
SELECT DISTINCT Label
FROM Contracts_Label
WHERE Channels IS NULL)
THEN LEFT JOIN Contracts_Label R
ON U.Label = R.Label
AND R.ContractLevel = 'LabelLevel'
END
;
```

I never learned much about indexing, DB tuning, query optimization, etc. But I have tried this query without any keys, with primary keys on both tables, with indexes based on individual columns, indexes based on multiple columns. Nothing I've tried gets that query to run "right".

Can anyone tell me the best approach from here? I've been alternating between researching and trial& error for about 5 days now...

Comment: If you're going to down vote me, will you please explain why?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but don't worry about drive-by downvotes. Anyone can downvote for any reason. Some people downvote because they can't understand your problem. Some people downvote because you're using MySQL, but they're fans of some other database. The downvoting system on Stack Overflow is broken because it disproportionately gives a voice to the biggest jerks out there. Don't take it personally.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I've found too many downvotes leads to being barred from asking questions.

Update: even a simple sum(`USD.Payable`) on the U table takes forever. I think I need to normalize the table. Sound right?

Comment: `JOIN ... ON CASE` will always be slow, because it can't use any index (with some exceptions which are not relevant here).

Comment: Here's the OQ's data in a fiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/047a1b/1/0

Comment: The sample data is a bit puzzling: I don't see any hits between your table of tracks and your table of rights.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your `rights` table is a union of various kinds of payment terms for artists. It looks like you're trying to get a listing of tracks with the terms for each one.

It looks like released tracks are paid by a match on barcode (UPC). Other kinds are paid by artists or labels.

Here's a way to do that task without an hour-long grind followed by a timeout. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/047a1b/4/0)

```
SELECT U.*,
       COALESCE(rel.ContractLevel, artist.ContractLevel, label.ContractLevel) ContractLevel,
       COALESCE(rel.Payee, artist.Payee, label.Payee) Payee,
       COALESCE(rel.Rate_percent, artist.Rate_percent, label.Rate_percent) Rate_percent,
       COALESCE(rel.startdate, artist.startdate, label.startdate) startdate,
       COALESCE(rel.expirationdate, artist.expirationdate, label.expirationdate) expirationdate

FROM all_ufo U
LEFT JOIN rights rel ON U.UPC = rel.UPC AND rel.ContractLevel = 'ReleaseLevel' 
LEFT JOIN rights artist ON  U.Artist = artist.Artist   AND artist.ContractLevel='ArtistLevel'
LEFT JOIN rights label ON  U.Label = label.Label   AND label.ContractLevel='LabelLevel'
```

It reuses the `rights` table in multiple `LEFT JOIN` operations. It then uses the `COALESCE()` function to find a relevant non-null value (a value with a hit on an ON clause) for each row.

Comment: Thanks O. This solution did exactly what I needed! I have removed the data, but left the question, the SQL script, and the ERD. I also removed the SQL Fiddle Link.

Can you kill that Fiddle? It was cool, but I want to protect my client data now, as much as I can. Needed to share to get an answer .. I hope you understand.

BTW, SQL Fiddle is cool. Didn't know about that one. Thanks!

Comment: Uh oh. Your data is yours, but when you posted it to StackOverflow you gave the community a perpetual license to use it. Editing your question doesn't erase it, because people can look at your question's edit history.

Comment: yeah, i know. and i knew then, too. i just want to do what i can. hopefully, not too many people will be hunting through the edit history of some arcane SQL question on SO. And all they'll find is about .003% of the data - no damage possible in any way. Like I said, I just want to do what I can, though.

Answer (score 2):

The simpler way to assure that you join to just one row in R is to add a primary key column to R, and reference that primary key. Then all your complex logic about contract levels disappears. A row in U can reference only one row in R.

```
ALTER TABLE rights 
     ADD COLUMN rights_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
     ADD PRIMARY KEY (rights_id);
ALTER TABLE all_ufo ADD COLUMN rights_id INT;
```

Treat the details about the contract level as *attributes* of the row in R, not the *identity* of the row. That is, once you have matches U to the correct row in R, then you can find out what level of contract it is.

```
SELECT ...
FROM all_ufo U
JOIN rights R ON U.rights_id = R.rights_id
WHERE R.Channels IS NULL;
```

P.S.: There are lots of other things in your SQL that make one say "WTF?" For example:

- `CASE` in SQL is only an expression, you can't embed `JOIN` clauses and other stuff in each case. It isn't like the `case` construct in C++. Read about MySQL's `IF` and `CASE` here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case
- Why use TEXT and BIGINT for nearly every column? There are good reasons to choose data types that are more appropriate to each column. If you don't know your data well enough to choose data types, then you probably haven't thought out your project enough.
- Quantity is DOUBLE? That means you can have a quantity that isn't a whole integer value? Seems unlikely.
- USD.Payable is DOUBLE? You should never use FLOAT or DOUBLE for currency, because of rounding behavior. [If I had a dime for every time I've seen someone use FLOAT to store currency, I'd have $999.997634.](https://twitter.com/billkarwin/status/347561901460447232)
- Avoid using a column name with a dot in it. SQL *allows* you to use punctuation and special characters in names, but you'll have to delimit the column names every time you use them. If you use _ instead of a dot, then you don't have to delimit the column name.

Comment: The middle 4 bullets are all because the tables were created by a dbWriteTable command in R.

The other 2 are because I'm 100% self-taught in MySQL, and I only know what I've learned when I needed to do something. I'll investigate further on the CASE expression. (I saw something in the MySQL manual about there being CASE *statements* and CASE *expressions*, and the 2 are different?

Comment: Yes, CASE statements are used only in stored routines and triggers. CASE expressions are used in any query. But neither of these can be used in the way you tried! :-)

Comment: Right now I'm running the COALESCE suggestion. Meanwhile, can you help me understand this? The problem as I understand it is that the U table - about 600k rows - doesn't *have* any references to R. I need to create that. In other words, I would still have to populate U.rights_id. See what I mean, or am I missing something? Thanks, by the way. This is how I learn: need to get something done, loads of research and trial & error, and then sometimes takin' it to the boards. It's a messy way to learn, but I am learning!

Comment: Yes, you need to set the values of U.rights_id. It will be tedious, but after it's set up correctly, future queries should be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

For what you have to work with, you might try the following as a UNION.  Try each on their own merit criteria.  The results will all be accumulated into one result set.  Based on the UPC being the primary qualified query, then to artists and last by the label.

Now, if a given record qualifies for multiple or all parts and you only want it to appear ONCE, you might be able to just apply "select DISTINCT " in the main loop to prevent the duplicates from being pulled in from the artist and label UNION portions.

```
SELECT *
   FROM all_ufo U
   JOIN rights R
      ON U.UPC = R.UPC
      AND R.UPC IS NOT NULL
      AND R.Channels IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT *
   FROM all_ufo U
   JOIN rights R
     ON U.Artist = R.Artist
     AND R.Artist IS NOT NULL
     AND R.Channels IS NULL
UNION
SELECT *
   FROM all_ufo U
   JOIN rights R
     ON U.Label = R.Label
     AND R.Label IS NOT NULL
     AND R.Channels IS NULL
```

Comment: I'm going to try this approach right after the COALESCE suggestion (above) finishes running, which I'm assured won't be an hour-long grind. :)

I had already partitioned *rights* into 3 separate tables - because I'm thinking of moving all this into a Neo4j model anyway, for future data that comes in. So I want to try your UNION suggestion, but on those 3 separate tables. Thanks!